# Laravel file upload starts downloading page

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, upload, routes

My form is working but when I add a file, Laravel starts downloading the following page:

[image]

The home controller function "upload" is not called if there was a file uploaded.

```
//##### home.blade.php
<?php
     echo Form::open(['route' => 'home.upload', 'files' => true]);
     echo Form::text('name', null);
     echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
     echo Form::label('file', 'Upload File');
     echo Form::file('file', null, ['id' => 'file']);
     echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
     echo Form::submit('Submit!');
     echo Form::close(); 
?>


//##### web.php
Route::post('/upload', [
    'as'    => 'home.upload',
    'uses'  => 'Home@upload'
]);

//##### Home.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class Home extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return view('home');
    }

    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
         var_dump($request->hasFile('sql'))exit;
    }
 }
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: What is the url when submitting?

Comment: URL in browser is / but the post request routes to /upload.
The type is x-httpd-php when a file is sent. Without a file the type is html.
I think here is a problem.

Comment: I'd say it doesn't post to the correct route. Can you check the source html in your browser when on home?

Comment: Action of the form is correct "/upload".
If there is no file to upload it routes correct and calls the upload() function.

Comment: Ok! I recognize I didn't fully read your posted image. If the route is correct and you obviously doesn't get the var_dump then it must be, as it say, something wrong with your server. A tip is to use Laravels `dd()` instead of `var_dump` and then `exit` - `dd($request->hasFile('sql'))`

Comment: On the same sevrer file upload is working without laravel framework.
Thanks for your tip ;).

Comment: Ok! The output however is not from the framework, it is from your Apache server

Comment: Does your php version match the requirements?

Comment: Yes. It's PHP7 and all required extensions are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
It had nothing to do with laravel.

The security configuration by the hoster caused the error.
For further information: https://www.strato.de/faq/article/136/Fehler-503-(Error-'Service-unavailable')-bei-der-Verwendung-von-POST-Requests.html